# Where can I find the Windows 7 (x64) graphics card driver for an ASUS K30BD desktop PC?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

We just bought some ASUS K30BD desktop PCs for the office, which came pre-loaded with Windows 8 (x64).

After downgrading to Windows 7 (x64), I realized the ASUS website does not offer Windows 7 drivers for this model. Why would this be? Surely, Windows 7 should still be an option for at least the next few years? Bizarrely, they provide Windows 7 (x64) drivers for the other hardware components... just not the graphics card.

Here's the link for the driver download page on the ASUS site:

http://www.asus.com/ca-en/Desktops/K30BD/HelpDesk_Download/

Here's a screenshot which shows the limited options on the ASUS site:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why they the Windows 7 drivers wouldn't be an option (when they are for some of the other hardware components)?

Also (and more importantly) can anyone help me track down this driver?

For what it's worth, the CPU on this PC is an AMD Sempron 3850 APU with Radeon R3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking for questions are off topic, maybe you are able to rephrase your question.

Comment: How do you know this driver exists? Why should it exist? It's up the manufacturer to support what they choose to support. Did you email Asus and ask? Did you try the W8 driver?

Comment: The Windows 8 driver doesn't work unfortunately! The Windows 7 driver should exist because they provide Windows 7 support for all of the other hardware components of the PC. What would be the point of them doing so if they weren't going to do so for the graphics card?

Comment: AMD and Nvidia distribute their own drivers.  If this hardware was only ever sold with Windows 8.1 instead of Windows 8.0 its unlikely ASUS would spend its resources validating its drivers against Windows 7. **You didn't tell us which discrete graphics card you have in your system.** I cannot provide an answer to your question without this information. If they came with `Windows 8.1` not `Windows 8.0` you should clarify that information.The display driver model changed in `Windows 8.1` this means `Windows 8` drivers do not work for `Windows 8.1` or at the very least can allow for stability prb

Comment: @Ramhound it was only ever sold with Windows 8.1 as far as I can see and yet I *did* find the Windows 7 64-bit driver. Instead of going the ASUS driver page route, I used the AMD autodetect utility. It recognized it as a Radeon HD 8200 /R3 Series video card and installed the Windows 7 x64 driver in seconds. Problem solved.

Comment: You have to read what I said.  ASUS isn't going to spend resources to test drivers they release against an OS they didn't sell on the device.  AMD already spent those resources awhile ago so its not sweat off their back to continue to support on Windows 7.

Comment: @Dave I know this driver exists because I subsequently found and installed it.

Comment: @Austin''Danger''Powers - Dave was talking about the driver published by ASUS.  What you found is a generic AMD driver published by AMD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the missing Windows 7 video card driver I was looking for on the AMD (*not* ASUS site) last week.

The moral of the story is: if your computer manufacturer doesn't make it easy to find the driver... don't give up! Try the AMD or Intel (as appropriate) autodetect utility.

I ran the AMD autodetect utility. It recognized my video card, recommended a reassuringly large download (350 MB or so) and had us up and running on Windows 7 in no time at all.

Screenshot showing the video card no longer showing up as a generic VGA device:

[image]

[image]

Hopefully this helps anyone else looking to downgrade their Windows 8 ASUS PC (or any other model for that matter) where the OEM manufacturer does not make it easy to find the Windows 7 version of the driver.

Comment: I told you to do this below

Comment: I tried your link but they were to the wrong driver - the installer said it didn't match the hardware. Using the auto-detect utility turned out the best way to go here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking AMD graphic drivers are standard and the driver download is the same as you would find on the AMD website.

Lenovo M79 has the same graphics chipset as your machine and they provide a Windows 7 Drive [here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds100769)

Hopefully that link will be valid for some time. They provide 32 and 64 bit for whatever your needs are.

Try that and let me know how you get on!

Comment: Unfortunately, when I installed the driver and rebooted, nothing happened. Any other ideas?

Comment: Strange, if you go to Control Panel, Administrator Tools, Computer Management, Device Manager, open up display adapters, firstly what is the name of the device listed here? Also if you double click the device and then go to Details Drop down to Hardware IDs can you comment back with the top result? I should be able to locate a driver for you.

Comment: It's currently showing as "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" in Device Manager. The hardware ID is PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_9836&SUBSYS_86231043&REV_00

Comment: It's not on many of the device databases, it could be an APU (built on to the CPU). Can you try going to http://support.amd.com/en-us/download and running the auto-detect tool to detect the device and download you a driver.

Comment: @CharlesH - The [desktop](http://www.asus.com/Desktops/K30BD/overview/) in question didn't come with an APU based on the fact it came with a AM1 processor.

Comment: @Ramhound: The CPU is showing in Device Manager as: "AMD Sempron 3850 APU with Radeon R3". Doesn't this mean it did come with an APU?

Comment: @Austin''Danger''Powers - It does but it also means you have something other than a **K30BD** because ASUS's website is pretty clear on the subject.  If you had a K30BD then GPU should have been a R5 not an R3 or a Nvidia card.